# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400 Web API MVC

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have created a web api, and trying to post data from ajax using that api.
web api is working for post request when i am trying from Postman plugin, but not working when we are posting through ajax call using json data.

We are getting Error of *XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:922/api/leaddetails/createlead. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400*

Here is the ajax call code:

```
function SaveLead() {

        var Lead = {
            "lead_owner": "Pritam",
            "company_name": "C",
            "title": "T",
            "first_name": "Santosh",
            "last_name": "M",
            "address1": "Rajasthan",
            "address2": "d",
            "city": "d",
            "state": "d",
            "country": "d",
            "postal_code": "d",
            "email": "vaya@gmail.com",
            "phone": "d",
            "website": "d",
            "mobile": "8787878787",
            "lead_status": "d",
            "lead_source": "d",
            "industry": "d",
            "annual_revenue": "d",
            "skype_id": "d",
            "campaign_source": "d",
            "description": "d",
            "created_by": "A",
            "updated_by": "a"
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: 'http://localhost:922/api/leaddetails/createlead',
            data: JSON.stringify(Lead),
            crossOrigin: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res) {
                alert("The result is : " + res);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        })



    }
```

Here is my web.config file:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV"/>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
</handlers>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I have tried to post from Postman plugin. From there it is posting data perfectly.

Comment: Even though you are connecting to localhost, you are connecting on port 922, so the request is considered cross-origin. Have you enabled CORS on the server?

Comment: Yes I have enabled it in web.config

Comment: probably best to show your config and how you've done it, as it's easy to get wrong.

Comment: I have updated my question with web.config file

Comment: Get Fiddler and compare both requests to the server (Postman vs jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer from a friend. I don't know this is the solution or not but changing ajax syntax worked for me.

```
    var apiurl = 'http://localhost:922/api/leaddetails/createlead';
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function SaveLead() {
    var Lead = {
            "lead_owner": "Pritam",
            "company_name": "C",
            "title": "T",
            "first_name": "Sourav",
            "last_name": "M",
            "address1": "Bhilai",
            "address2": "d",
            "city": "d",
            "state": "d",
            "country": "d",
            "postal_code": "d",
            "email": "vaya@gmail.com",
            "phone": "d",
            "website": "d",
            "mobile": "8787878787",
            "lead_status": "d",
            "lead_source": "d",
            "industry": "d",
            "annual_revenue": "d",
            "skype_id": "d",
            "campaign_source": "d",
            "description": "d",
            "created_by": "A",
            "updated_by": "a"
        };



        a.open('POST',apiurl,true),
         $.ajax({

             url: apiurl,
             type: "POST",
             ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: Lead,
             crossOrigin: true,
             dataType: "json",
             cache: false,
             complete: function (res) {
                 alert("Data Added Successfully");
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert("Error");
             }
         })

    }
```

Thanks all for replying.